# microsoft word on mac, how to put one sentence at the middle of the page

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I want to put a one sentence in the first page of each of my chapters.

I did that as this screenshot shows:

[image: My Way]

However, my way is totally stupid because I kept hitting enter, enter, enter 'til I reached the middle of the page, what's the standard way to do that please?

I'm using word on macbook pro

```
word:mac 2011
version: 14.5.9 (151119)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Insert a text field: Tab <kbd>Insert</kbd> → <kbd>Shapes</kbd><sup>?</sup> → <kbd>Text area</kbd><sup>?</sup>. It is normally this icon: [image] under "Basic shapes". The first time you can find it under "Basic shapes", all the next times under "Last used shapes", because Word goes remember it.

   [image]
2. Choose the position of the text area: <kbd>Layout</kbd> → <kbd>position</kbd>.

   [image]
3. Choose for the text alignment "middle" by <kbd>align text</kbd>.

   [image]
4. Choose for the border "no border" by <kbd>Outline of shape</kbd><sup>?</sup>.

   [image]

Normally must your text now be placed in the middle of your page.

**P.S. 1:** I'm sorry but I use a dutch version of MS office on a Windows 10 device. But I think it is the same way of working.

**P.S. 2:** A question mark (<sup>?</sup>) are translations that I'm not sure that they are correct.

Comment: Oh oh :) :) this word is completely different than mine, and though I love dutch langauge, but i'm really bad on it. :(

Comment: @sarah: which version of word do you use, madam?

Comment: In the insert shapes, i have too many shapes, but there is no label on them to know which one is the `textarea` you've mentioned

Comment: There is insert TextBox, will that work please ?

Comment: @sarah: A textbox is normaly this icon: http://i.stack.imgur.com/4GZBN.png An A with four stripes.

Comment: @sarah: the label comes automatic when your mouse hovering the icons for a short time.

Comment: first said textarea, and now you gave me a photo of a textbox, which one is correct, textarea of textbox please ?

Comment: @sarah: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33365/discussion-between-luis-and-sarah).

Comment: sorry i can't chat now, anyway, i guess it's workign with me now, thanks

Comment: @sarah: I don't know what is correct "text box" or "text area". I use a Dutch version of Word. I don't know how Microsoft has translate it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new paragraph style for your quotes.

In its paragraph properties, add spacing before of say 300pt.  This will add that amount of white space immediately above your text without all those paragraph marks.